# Very simple span and button on the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My only problem is that the button is not in the same line as the span.

How do I fix this?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Test</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `float` the `.text-right` for example. [See my example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/topr/vrkuta5w/)

```
.text-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```css
.text-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<td>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Test</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Almost but now the text is not vertically alligned with the button

Comment: @user10498758 If you want that, you'll need to add some `margin` to the left text and `float` it as well. See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/topr/js1u0krh/1/).

Comment: I don't really like to give fixed margins. I tried vertical-allign but it doesn't work. Isn't there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to easily achieve this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Test</button>
  </div>
</div>
```